# C# Winforms - Force write a property value of a user control to resx file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I've a user control that has a `byte[]` property. The array can became huge also in design time. When Visual Studio saves the form it saves it to the cs file with this method

```
this.ctlShowSpreadsheet1.SerializationContent = new byte[] {
        ((byte)(80)),
        ((byte)(75)),
        ((byte)(3)),
        ((byte)(4)),
        ((byte)(20)),
        ((byte)(0)),
        ((byte)(2)),
        ((byte)(0)),
        ((byte)(8)),
        ((byte)(0)),
        ((byte)(128)),
        ((byte)(84)),
        ((byte)(29)),
        ...
```

Is there a way to force that the array of bytes is saved to the resx files?
I try changing `DesignerSerializationVisibility` but without results.

Comment: You can, but it doesn't help. You can add `[Localizable(true)]` to the property and change the form's `Localizable` property to `true`. Then it puts the actual data in the `resx` file, but it will then add a reference to each element into the `designer.cs` file anyway.

Comment: Have you tried the `LocalizableAttribute` and set `Localizable`

Comment: @MatthewWatson I can't be sure that the `UserControl` user sets `Localizable = true` on the form. I can't understand _Then it puts the actual data in the resx file, but it will then add a reference to each element into the designer.cs file anyway_. Will VS set an element fo the array for each element in the resx (so exactly like before but reading every single byte from the resx?) Can't the resx store an array and VS read and set the whole array in a single statement?

Comment: What I mean is, although it puts the data into the .resx file, the Designer.cs file contains a line like `(byte)(resources.GetObject("testUserControl1.Data"))),` for EVERY element of the array. Which seems to be much worse!

Comment: Hmm, having to edit this property sounds very unpractical.  Not [Localizable], it takes the [Serializable] attribute on the underlying property type to convince the designer that an object of that type can be written to the .resx file.  How that got to be byte[] to store a spreadsheet (?) is very murky.  MemoryStream is serializable.

Comment: @HansPassant your solution works as usual!!!

Answer (score 1):

If a property is of type of a `Serializable` type, then the designer serializes it to the resource file.

So in your case, you can create a serializable byte list and store your byte list using it. Just keep in mind, the designer need your serializable class be located in a different assembly.

### Example

In the below example, I've created a control having a byte list property which will be stored in resx file of the form. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Create a new Project of *Windows Forms* Project as your main project.
2. Add a new project of *Windows Forms Control Library* to the solution.
3. Add a c# file containing following code to the control library project.
4. Add a reference of your control library project to the main windows forms project.
5. Build the solution.
6. Drop an instance of `MyControl` on your form.
7. Then in property grid find `ByteList` property and expand it.
8. Edit `Bytes` property.
9. Save the form
10. See the property value is saved in resource file of the form. Also designer generates code to get the value from resources:

    ```
    this.myControl1.ByteList = ((WindowsFormsControlLibrary1.SerializableByteList)
        (resources.GetObject("myControl1.ByteList")));
    ```

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyControl: UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        ByteList = new SerializableByteList();
    }
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public SerializableByteList ByteList { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SerializableByteList
{
    public SerializableByteList()
    {
        Bytes = new List<byte>();
    }
    public List<byte> Bytes { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**

For more information about designer serialization, take a look at [Customizing Code Generation in the .NET Framework Visual Designers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973818.aspx).

> ***Using Binary Serialization***
>
> Not all types lend themselves cleanly to code generation. For example, how would you serialize a bitmap into code? You could encode
>   it as a string, but for even a moderately sized bitmap the string
>   could be much larger than the rest of the code in the file. The
>   Designer solves this problem by persisting binary types into the
>   resources file that pushes the values into the manifest for the .NET
>   Framework application. Then, when the application is initialized, it
>   can load the values back out of the Assembly's manifest.
>
> The code generator follows this order when trying to serialize a type:
>
> - Built in serialization of primitive types (string, bool, integer, float, etc.)
> - InstanceDescriptor serialization for custom types
> - Binary serialization for types that are marked as Serializable.

Keep in mind that you can control the way that designer serialize the
 object by implementing `ISerializable` interface for your class.